# Regex Processing using software supplied by Kimonolabs

Tags: regex, web-scraping

I am attempting to use software supplied by [Kimonolabs](https://www.kimonolabs.com/) to get a list of list of doctors from a web site. The problem I am having is that a string I have scraped from the web site has an address and a zip code that is separated by a `<br>` tag.

Kimono uses this syntax for a regex:

```
/^()(.*?)()$/
```

first group => to the left of the required content

second group => this is what should get extracted

third group => to the right of the required content

Specifically, here are the regex expressions that I have tried:

```
/^()(.*?)(\<)$/ 
/^()(.*?)(\n)$/
/^()(.*?)(\r)$/
```

And, this is the site I'm trying to scrape: http://www.jameda.de/

Here's an example line that I am trying to parse via a regex:

```
<p>Altlaufstr. 22<br>85635 Höhenkirchen-Siegertbrn</p>
```

However, each of the regex patterns that I have tried do not capture any data. I am having trouble understanding regexes because I am finding that the reference materials I have found are pretty complicated.

Comment: Could you copy an extract of the source for question sanity and that I'm not able to understand where you're looking at in this site.

Comment: http://www.jameda.de/arztsuche/?new_search=1&gruppe=ZA&fachgebiet=&geo=48%2E015846%5F11%2E717310%5F%5F85635%5FH%F6henkirchen%2DSiegertsbrunn%5Fhoehenkirchen%2Dsiegertsbrunn%5FBayern%5F0&address=H%F6henkirchen-Siegertsbrunn&was=Zahnarzt&was_i=Zahnarzt&address_i=h%F6henkrichen&was_sel=1&address_sel=0&h_what=gruppe%253DZA%2526fachgebiet%253D&h_where=geoball%253D11%25252E717310%25252C48%25252E015846%25252C0%25252E5%2526geo%253D48%25252E015846%25255F11%25252E717310%25255F%25255F85635%25255FH%2525F6henkirchen%25252DSiegertsbrunn%25255Fhoehenkirchen%25252Dsiegertsbrunn%25255FBayern%25255F0

Comment: https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/4adp9n74?apikey=B8CQhlHIsolXdJnXfFEQ79kVMIsefpvC

Comment: First Link: Source
Second Link: JSON

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to match German zipcodes, which are always 5 digits. This will do it:

`/(<br\/?>)(\d{5})()/`

Breakdown:

`<br\/?>` indicates that it must be preceded by a `<br>` tag (with or without slash)

`\d{5}` is 5 digits

Note: leave out the `^` and `$` anchors that were in the default kimono regex because this regex is not trying to match the entire text - just the ZIP.

Comment: As far as I understood should the expression
`/^(<br\/?>)(.*?)()$/`
find everything behind the br.

So the scrapped paragraph looks like this:
e.g.
`<p>Altlaufstr. 22<br>85635 Höhenkirchen-Siegertbrn</p>`
If I use `/^()(.*?)()$/` it returns Altlaufstr. 2285635 Höhenkirchen-Siegertbrn
if I use `/^(<br\/?>)(.*?)()$/` it doesn't return anything at all :-(

Comment: I have added your example to your original post, and have updated my answer. The reason `/^(<br\/?>)(.*?)()$/` doesn't match is that you have the `^` anchor, specifying that the `<br>` is at the beginning of the string.